# Programmatic Control of Firefox

Tags: .net, firefox

Is there a .NET-accessible (i.e. .NET or COM) library that I can use to programmatically control Firefox? I'm looking for something that is a bit like ShDocVw.dll for IE. Doesn't have to do all that much, basically all I want to be able to do is programmatically add a bookmark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the firefox bookmarks are stored within the Places.sqlite file within the users [firefox profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder#Where_is_my_profile_folder.3F).

There is an ado.net c# to sqlite connector available at http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/.

edit:

Very good tutorial:
http://web.archive.org/web/20100208133236/http://www.mikeduncan.com/sqlite-on-dotnet-in-3-mins/

Comment: Interesting tutorial! Thanks for that info, I'll check it out tomorrow!