# Programmatically add a bookmark to Chrome

Tags: .net, google-chrome

In the same vein as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395914/programmatic-control-of-firefox), is there a .NET-accessible library that'll let me add bookmarks for Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

The format of the Bookmarks file is a `json` text file, which you can manipulate as needed. In OS X you find this file at

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but perhaps due to the fact that there's no info on the structure of that JSON file (how does one modify it to add a bookmark?)

Comment: This still works well, but an important note is that you cannot have Chrome running while updating the bookmarks file; it will revert. And at least in my Gnome, I had to go to some lengths to make sure Chrome was truly, completely closed.

Answer (score 0):

The Bookmarks are stored in a SQLite database that you can access.  I found [this](http://unlockforus.blogspot.com/2008/09/how-opening-google-chrome-sqlite-v3.html) page which has some more information.

Comment: I don't think this is correct - about halfway down http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=501d9a38a1976525&hl=en is a line that reads: 'For any programmers who are interested, the format of the Bookmarks file is json'

Comment: you are correct.  The format is /now/ in Json, which means that once you have the file it is really easy to edit.